# how to paste multiple line to a command line prompt of a scala stdIn process?

Tags: linux, scala, command-line, stdin

I have a scala program running to prompt for user input in a loop, like
enter name:
enter age:
continue?:

How can I prepare a string of multiple users' input and copy and paste it once into the prompt to simulate user input of mutiple user info.

I tried with john\n26\nc\nlucy\22\c...

```
val acctList = ListBuffer.empty[UserInfo]
breakable {
  while (true) {
    try {
      println(s"enter name: ")
      val myName = scala.io.StdIn.readLine
      val stdIn = System.console()
      println(s"enter age for $myName")
      val myAge = scala.io.StdIn.readLine
      val acct = UserInfo(myName, myAge)
      acctList += acct
      println(s"enter c to continue: ")
      val cont = scala.io.StdIn.readLine
      if (cont != "c") break
    }
    catch {
      case e: NumberFormatException => println("number format exception caught:" + e.toString)
      case e: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException => println("string index out of range:" + e.toString)
      case e: Exception => println("exception caught:" + e.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

paste "John\n26\nc\nLucy\n22\nx" into the first prompt, I should be able to read in acctList as ({"John", 26}, {Lucy, 22})

Comment: Automating STDIN/STDOUT interactions is not a trivial task. There's a complete [scripting language](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) developed to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question I'm sure almost all programming students encounter at some point. The essence of your question seems to be "How can I simulate side-effects (input/output in this example) in my program?" You can imagine the same issue if your code called `database.insert(...)` instead of `scala.io.StdIn.readLine` or `println(...)`. It's all the same problem really. In a test environment, how can you feed input to a program like this?

I would recommend looking at this [excellent example](https://gist.github.com/jdegoes/1b43f43e2d1e845201de853815ab3cb9) (explained in [this video by John De Goes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxudIMiOo68&t=4075s)) of your *exact* problem, addressed in a functional style. The final outcome of the program may be overkill for your app, and one of the intermediate programs shown might be the perfect example for you. I don't recommend seeking out true answer to your original question, but rather you should refactor the program so that you don't *need* to find an answer to that question.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't believe that JDG's brilliant work on ZIO changes the fact that, when prompted, the input `a\nb` is one string of 4 characters and **not** two inputs of 1 character each. I believe _that_ is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't answer the exact question. I'm providing a solution that the question author probably hadn't considered, and which might be favorable in their case. Your comment mentioning expect is more in line with the initial intent of the question.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried shell input redirection?

```
echo -e "john\n26\nc\nlucy\n22\n" >autoinput.txt
scala yourscript.scala 0<autoinput.txt
```

if shell input redirection does not work
the "expect" family would be the best answer to automate interactive programs, but that would be  too much to talk about